# MariaDB Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.80.4' (using password: YES) for some databases

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB up and running inside a docker container, and I can connect to it using `adminer`. I have more than 10 databases in it. I can access all data from `adminer`.

In my code I'm using [EF Core MariaDB provider](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) and I still have access to some of the databases.

All of my connection strings use the same user (root) and the same password.

The all inherit from the same `DatabaseContext`. But for some databases, I receive this error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.80.4' (using password: YES)
```

What could be the reason?

Please note that a lot of questions on this site are not addressing this issue. They either have access, or they don't have access at all. Or they have not set the password for the root user.

This is the result of `SELECT user, password FROM mysql.user`:

```
User,Password
mariadb.sys,""
root,*5D7D1AA0BB8037E0CF0080B8A6B2DF7D189EBD7B
root,*5D7D1AA0BB8037E0CF0080B8A6B2DF7D189EBD7B
```

I don't know why do I have two root users.

This is the result of `show grants`:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO root@% IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*5D7D1AA0BB8037E0CF0080B8A6B2DF7D189EBD7B' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Comment: Execute `SHOW GRANTS` and check does your account have enough privileges.

Comment: @Akina, my user is root. Can root user lack privileges? I have not chaneged anything.

Comment: Have you checked already? have you ensured that **current** user have needed privileges?

Comment: This is the result of `show grants`: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*5D7D1AA0BB8037E0CF0080B8A6B2DF7D189EBD7B' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: The grants for root don't look right. Mine shows `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD` .... the `*.*` is for all databases. Your seems to show for none.

Comment: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*5D7D1AA0BB8037E0CF0080B8A6B2DF7D189EBD7B' WITH GRANT OPTION
` I also have it. I guess the first time I messed it up while posting it as a comment.

Comment: You have two root user accounts because one will be `root@localhost` and the other `root@%` which you are using. Your grants look correct. How are you starting the container (env variables, and exact mariadb container (and version))? Is the access denied on connection or during some operation? The [CI of Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://dev.azure.com/pomelo-efcore/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/_build/results?buildId=1414&view=logs&j=b3c846c9-2523-532e-80e2-f570cd8fdd0f&t=07f9904a-a0fe-5d40-32fb-90093395df21) runs against mariadb-10.3 -> 10.6. Can you show a minimal code example?

Comment: @danblack, after hours of frustration, I restarted my laptop and it worked. I don't know what might be the cause. I wish they would include more information in this error.